# CountIf in Excel with formula in criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, countif

I'm trying to use a CountIf in Excel (2010) with a formula as criteria. Something like this:

```
=CountIf(rawdata!$AK:$AK;bitAnd(rawdata!$AK:$AK;F$3))
```

whereas *BitAnd* is a user-defined VBA function for a bitwise AND-operation:

```
Public Function bitAnd(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
bitAnd = a And b
End Function
```

The task is to count all rows that have a certain bit flag set. For example, I'd like to count all rows that have its LSB set to 1 (such as 0001, 0101,...). That is, to do something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
IF bitAnd(1;any number in the range) == 1 THEN count
```

Obviously this doesn't work with CountIf, but is there any other elegant solution using formulas (instead of coding custom functions in VBA)? Any suggestions?

Comment: do the calculation (criteria) in column next to data... refer the countif criteria to those cells

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(INT(($A3:$A19)/F$2),2)*1)
```

Here, `$A3:$A19` is the source range to test, F2 is `=2^(F$1-1)`, and F1 is the order of the bit you want to extract (1 is the LSB, etc.)
Of course, you could write a straight formula `=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(INT(($A3:$A19)/2^(F$1-1),2))*1)`.
You should adapt absolute/relative indexing to your needs, to be able to conveniently copy-and-paste (as I did for testing the formulas).

Note that this is useful for extracting a single bit, as you were asking for. A "complete" bitwise AND might be constructed on this basis (although there are likely better options).

For the specific case of [Excel 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/bitand-function-HA102753251.aspx) (as of now, not your target), using the `BITAND` worksheet function along with `COUNTIF` or `SUMPRODUCT` should put you on track, and here you have a "complete" bitwise AND available (I do not have Excel 2013 to test this).

Comment: Hi, that's a nice approach, I didn't know that. However, it only works if there's just a ONE bit flag set to 1. In my case, it might as well happen that there are several bits set. That's why I tried to work with a bitwise AND. Do you have a suggestion how to deal with it?

Comment: @user1707493 - I do not understand what you mean. I tested this on all numbers *n* in the interval [0,17] (i.e., many of them have more than one bit set to 1), extracting bits *b* #1, #2 or #3, and it works. For example, *n and 0010b*. As said, it cannot compute *n and 0110b*, if that is what you mean. I would google something like "excel bitwise and" (I actually did that, tried a couple of options that I found, none working). That is probably worth another question, as it is interesting as a closed question on its own.